# links and formatting, HTTP makes a difference?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, anchor, href

So this is how I want all links to appear on the page:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
```

Except for a vertical navigation menu in a DIV that has links in white with a green background (blue on hover).  NOTE: this navMenu only links to other pages on my site ("home.html","contact.html",etc) and uses relative paths (ie - the file name only).

```
#navMenu {
    width: 105px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#navMenu > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navMenu > ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: small;
}

#navMenu > ul li a:link, a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: #999900;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navMenu > ul li a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

So when I look at links in a page that are outside the navMenu DIV, most of them are external (to another site) and look like this:

```
<a href="http://somewhere.com">Link</a>
```

and are working with the blue colors and such as defined by the default "a" selectors.

BUT (get this) - any link (even if it is outside the navMenu DIV) that is to another page on the site with a relative path:

```
<a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
```

is being treated with the navManu formatting (so the text is white).

BUT GET THIS - if I take any of those links (to internal pages) outside the navMenu DIV and just add "http://" to the HREF, it takes from the "a" selectors and the link turns blue.

What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you already visited the link. Your CSS says that *any* link that has been visited should appear white. The first declaration that says it should be blue is overridden, and I think that this is your problem. Try changing the last two declarations to the following:

```
#navMenu > ul li a:link, #navMenu > ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: #999900;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navMenu > ul li a:hover, #navMenu > ul li a:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Note the specificity of the selectors.

Comment: I thought it had something to do with the selectors.  Rookie mistake - sorry.  Thanks for the help!!!!